# Magento 2: Use widget with standard product list template

Tags: product, collection, widget

Is there way to use the same template like the "new products" widget magento already has but with my own product collection?

I know how to make a widget but i don't how to attach the standard template and how to pass my productdata to it.

Any ideas where to start?